# ReactJS State and Local Variable

Tags: reactjs

Ref:
ReactJS documents page URL: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Is ***timerID*** in the assignment *this.timerID = setInterval* just a variable. Why is this not a *state*?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You *could* have it be a state variable, but that wouldn't make much sense since the state is meant to hold variables that relate to the current state of the UI. Also, state variables are meant to trigger a re-render if they are updated (with `setState()`).

Neither of these would make much sense for a timer ID to be stored in the state. In other words, it's not a state variable because:

1. The timerID doesn't express the representation of the UI in any way.
2. Updating the timerID shouldn't trigger a re-render.

---

The [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state) actually mention this:

> The state contains data specific to this component that may change over time. [...] If you don't use it in `render()`, it shouldn't be in the state. For example, you can put timer IDs directly on the instance.

Comment: Thank you. The other two responses too share almost similar thoughts, but yours is the most complete and unambiguous, so accepting.

Answer (score 3):

> Is timerID in the assignment this.timerID = setInterval just a
>   variable

Yes, `timerID` is a variable returned by the [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) function. It also is a normal property of `class Clock ...`.

> Why is this not a state?

Use `timerID` in `state` brings no benefits. It is only another place from `state` to store a shared variable within your class. Storing it in `state` only makes your `state` bigger and more complex (which is harder to manage) since `timerID` does not take place for the final view. Or more simpler, `timerID` is not used within `render`, so we don't need to put it in the `state`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can store `timerID` in state, but this is not a good practice, as you can 
read in the same documentation page:

> If you don't use something in render(), it shouldn't be in the state.

Every time that you update your state via `setState`, render method is invoking. So if this data doesn't change UI, then calling render method doesn't change anything and it will be a waste.

That is why all the 'helper' data, such as API requests, e.t.c is better to store as component-object keys.

Comment: This is basically exactly what I said, just rephrased.

Answer (score 1):

The timerID should not be state because it's not related to UI (when state changes page is re-rendered).
If it's in state then page will re-render after every change in timerID value.